# Google Colaboratory 使用時にポップアップウィンドウが小さく内容が読めないケースが発生する

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratoryの画面でホップアップウィンドウが表示されるのですが、枠が小さくて読めません。クリックしても大きくもできません。このような表示の方おられますでしょうか？どうしたら改善できるか教えてください。「警告」となってるホップアップウィンドウです。これを大きくしたいです。エラー内容は無視してください。よろしくお願いいたします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ウインドウが小さいと言うよりも文字が大きく表示されるために表示範囲をはみ出しているのでは？ ブラウザのテキスト表示に関する拡大縮小倍率を少しずつ小さい方(90%とか80%など)に変更してから表示されるような操作をしてみると何か変わるかもしれません。あるいはDevTool等で該当ポップアップウインドウのHTMLソースを表示させれば、内容そのものは読み取れるのでは？

Comment: 一時的に発生した現象の可能性もあるので、F5 や Ctrl + F5 でのリロードを試してみてください。常に再現するようであれば使っているブラウザ等の情報を質問本文に含めてみてください。

Comment: フォントサイズに対してブラウザのタブの高さが足りてないのかもしれないですね。